# Python3 Flask: "Function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'test_output'"

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pymongo

I'm just starting with FLASK and stumbled upon this error:

```
 test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'test_output'
```

Why is this happening? The functions is declared before calling it and usually this error means that the argument while calling the function is missing.

```
def foo(x):
    print (x)

foo(x)
```

So this is working, why doesn't it work in my script with flask?

Here is my "full" code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)

#app.config ['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'DBfoo'
app.config['MONGO_URI']     = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Test'


mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/TestRouteGet', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def test(test_output):
    print (test_output)

def get_Test():

    collection = mongo.db.TestCol

    if request.method == 'POST':

        test_input = "Test BlaBla"
        test(test_input)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When sending a POST request I should have the test_output ("Test Blabla") printed in the console.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function expects test_output argument, you should get this argument from the url string http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#url-building

```
@app.route('/TestRouteGet/<test_output>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Then you can make a request to /TestRouteGet/insert_your_string and your function will print received string.